# DITA: Override right-alignment for English text within Arabic file

Tags: alignment, arabic, dita

I am working on a series of computer manuals which are supplied as DITA code (a dialect of XML) and then translated before being rendered into PDFs. The PDF renderer automatically selects the RTL text direction and right-aligns the text in Hebrew and Arabic. However, there are some topics within the file that aren't translated, and it right-aligns them too. I have tried putting `dir="ltr"` within the `<topic>` tag, but that had no effect. I tried adding `align="left"` to the `<topic>` tag, then to the `<p>` (paragraph) clauses within it, but according to the DITA standard these tags don't recognise the `align` attribute, which is only available for various table elements. Is there a way to override the default (in this case, right-margin) alignment for a paragraph or larger block within a DITA file? Note that it is *not* feasible to rewrite the text using tables: we have to stick to the DITA structure supplied by the client.

Comment: It is very important to describe what XML format are you using before passing it to PDF formatter and what PDF formatter are you using. If you are using XSL-FO and DITA-OT bundled PDF2 plug-in to generate PDF, this plug-in does not supports `@dir` attribute at all and `@writing-mode` is determined in bookmap (map) level only. This means you may need more stylesheet work if you  adopt this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What PDF renderer are you using? If the DITA Open Toolkit, 1) What version, and 2) Are you using a custom plug-in?

You might find more help on the dita-users list which is hosted on groups.io.

Comment: It is called Antenna House. It contains a number of bugs in the rendering of left-to-right text within right-to-left documents, and I'm basically trying to find a workaround. I am only the engineer, so I don't think I can ask my employers to use different software or to get Antenna House to fix the bug.

Comment: How is your publishing started? I doubt you are sending your DITA files directly to Antenna House. Most people are using the DITA Open Toolkit, which processes the DITA files and then sends them to Antenna House. The DITA OT may be embedded inside of a CMS like SDL or Ixiasoft. Antenna House would be called late in the publishing toolchain.